# df.withcolumn is too slow when I iterate through the column data in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I am doing the AES Encryption for pyspark dataframe column.

I am iterating the column data, and replacing the column value with encrypted value using df.withcolumn, But it is too slow

I am looking for the alternative approach, But I did not get any

```
'''
for i in column_data:   
 obj= AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC,v)   
 ciphertext= obj.encrypt(i)

 df=df.withColumn(col,F.when(df[col]==i,str(ciphertext)).otherwise(df[col])) return df
'''
```

But it's taking long time.

Could you please suggest the other alternative

Answer (score 0):

Your code is slow because of your for-loop, as it forces Spark to run only on one thread.

Please provide an example of input and expected output and someone might be able to help you with rewriting your code.